# Не корректно работает бургер-меню (меню не появляется когда открыт бургер)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, scss

Сам крестик анимируется, и видно, что при уменьшении ширины экрана меню уезжает на верх. Но при нажатии на бургер меню не открывается. Был использован обнуляющий стиль и миксины. Я новичок, уже всю голову себе сломала, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
$('.wrapper').addClass('loaded');

$('.icon-menu').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("lock");
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus, :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus, a:active {
  outline: none;
}

aside, nav, footer, header, section {
  display: block;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input, button, textarea {
  font-family: "Lato";
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------ОБОЛОЧКА--------------------------*/
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------ОСНОВНАЯ СЕТКА--------------------------*/
.container {
  max-width: 1130px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ФАЙЛОВ--------------------------*/
.block {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.block img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
}
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slick-slider .slick-track {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------ОСНОВНОЙ БЛОК--------------------------*/
.page {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-screen {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*------------------------HEADER------------------------------*/
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
}
.header__row {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 85px;
}
.header__logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px);
  z-index: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .header {
    top: 15px;
  }
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
}
.menu__list li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 37.5px;
}
.menu__list li:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 110px 0 37.5px;
}
.menu__list li:nth-child(3) {
  padding: 0 37.5px 0 110px;
}
.menu__list li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #4d4959;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -1.5px 0 0 0;
}
.menu__list li:nth-child(2):after, .menu__list li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.menu__link {
  color: #4d4959;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.6px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu__body {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #4d4959;
    padding: 150px 0px 20px 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .menu__body.active {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  .menu__body__list {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .menu__body__list li {
    padding: 0 0 45px 0;
  }
  .menu__body__list li:nth-child(2), .menu__body__list li:nth-child(3) {
    padding: 0 0 45px 0;
  }
  .menu__body__list li:nth-child(2):after, .menu__body__list li:nth-child(3):after {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu__body__list li:last-child {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu__body__list li:after {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    right: 50%;
    top: 40px;
    margin: 0 -2px 0 0;
  }
  .menu__body__link {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu__icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .menu__icon span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #4d4959;
  }
  .menu__icon span:first-child {
    top: 0px;
  }
  .menu__icon span:last-child {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  .menu__icon.active span {
    transform: scale(0);
    background-color: white;
  }
  .menu__icon.active span:first-child {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 8px;
  }
  .menu__icon.active span:last-child {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Адаптивная верстка лендинга</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:regular,italic,700" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<main class="page">
<!--HEADER-->
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__row">
        <nav class="header__menu menu">
            <div class="menu__icon icon-menu">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__body">
                <ul class="menu__list">
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!--HEADER-->
    <div class="main-screen">
<div>
    <img class="block" src="img/Ресурс 1.png" alt="">
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
<!--HEADER-->
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__row">
        <nav class="header__menu menu">
            <div class="menu__icon icon-menu">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__body">
                <ul class="menu__list">
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
</header>
 <!--FOOTER-->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer__row">
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</main>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```